# Android PhoneStateListener is not working in sleep mode

Tags: android, phone-state-listener, sleep-mode

I'm writing an app, which listens to GSM signal strength. I've created a service, in which I put the PhoneStateListener. The problem is, that PhoneStateListener does not listen to any changes while phone is in sleep mode. I really need to solve that problem, could anyone help me with this?
I tried to use that code in onCreate() method:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "call_lock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

but it doesn't solve my problem, listener is still not listening in sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for your solution.Reconsider your code.For more information read this article [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778698/check-for-wifi-networks-signal-in-sleep-mode)